# How to make R filter syntax more user friendly?

Tags: r, filter, syntax

I am currently working on a R shiny project that need to load in dataset and add criteria to filter out observations.

my issue is when user is entering "flag=1 and condition>=2", the following will convert to "flag==1 and condition>==2" to be readable by R, which is not correct and show error definitely. Is there any function/package can make non-R user to type the condition they want?

```
    .....if (input$criteria_ad == ""){
      dat <- dat0
    }else if(endsWith(file_ad$name, '.sas7bdat')){
      ad <- data.frame(setDT(read_sas(file_ad$datapath)))
      
      rep_str <- c('<='='<=','>='='>=','='='==','and'='&','or'='|')
      
      ad <- filter(ad, eval(parse(text = str_replace_all(input$criteria_ad, rep_str))))
      
      dat <- inner_join(dat0, ad, by ='ID')
    }......
```

Comment: If using Shiny, I'd think it makes more sense to use a control widget (such as a slider) for users to enter criteria?

Comment: Thanks neilfws, but the user prefers to use more flexible input because the variables in the dataset are varied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using regex word-boundaries.

With word-boundaries:

```r
rep_str <- c('<='='<=','>='='>=','\\b=\\b'='==','and'='&','or'='|')
str_replace_all("flag=1 and condition>=2", rep_str)
# [1] "flag==1 & condition>=2"
```

You can do this for all instead of just the singular `=` with

```r
rep_str <- c('<='='<=','>='='>=','='='==','and'='&','or'='|')
names(rep_str) <- paste0("\\b", names(rep_str), "\\b")
rep_str
#  \\b<=\\b  \\b>=\\b   \\b=\\b \\band\\b  \\bor\\b 
#      "<="      ">="      "=="       "&"       "|" 
str_replace_all("flag=1 and condition>=2", rep_str)
# [1] "flag==1 & condition>=2"
```

FYI, since the first two elements of your `rep_str` are no-change, we can omit them from the vector.